# Solr search with array of values on field

Tags: solr, solarium

I'm new in Solr search. Can anyone help me for solr my problem. I have array of values and I want to add this in solr query like

```
$query->setQuery('field:[1,2,5]');
```

When I'm executing this then I get this error message

```
org.apache.solr.search.SyntaxError: Cannot parse 'tag_id:[1,2,5]': Encountered \" \"]\" \"] \"\" at line 1, column 13.\r\nWas expecting one of:\r\n    \"TO\" ...\r\n    <RANGE_QUOTED> ...\r\n    <RANGE_GOOP> ...\r\n
```

I'm stuck on this. Please help me.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

try with filter query

https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/solr/Common+Query+Parameters#CommonQueryParameters-Thefq(FilterQuery)Parameter

```
tag_id=cat:(1 OR 2 OR 5)
```