# How to search for comma separated values in solr?

Tags: solr

I want to search data in solr. I have a field which contains comma separated ids. How can I search for comma separated ids in solr? I have ids in an array for which I need the search like:

ids to search : [1,5]

ids in solr field: "1,2,3,4,5,6"

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31422013/solr-search-with-array-of-values-on-field

Comment: That answer can be condensed to ids:(1 2 3 4 5) as long as `q.op` or the default operator is `OR`, btw.

Answer (score 0):

To make the field in solr to be multi-valued and try like this :

```
q=field:*7*
```

Answer (score 0):

I get the correct result by using the **or** operator as mentioned by the @MathsLindh in comment. 
Thanks for responding. :)